# Is there a word that describes something as conditionally true?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that describes something as conditionally true? Is there a word that is used to define or describes something that's conditionally true, something whose truth is contingent on other things being true?

Comment: Yes, this is called a "conditional".  It's the best word to fit what you seem to want to say.

Comment: There are several words, including "conditional" and "contingent" which you have used in your questions. are you looking for a noun, an adjective, or something else? Since you have a couple of closely related words, consider looking up a thesaurus, such as https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/conditional.

Comment: Is there a word in your languages? Have you tried a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. We have the adjectives "true" and "false", and we can use modifiers like "maybe" or "sometimes"

So "Grass is green" is true. But "Apples are green" is *sometimes true*.

You can abbreviate this to "True False or Sometimes".

In formal logic, an statement statements are either true or false, and so quantifiers are used:

> All grass is green.
>
> There exists at least one green apple.
>
> It is not the case that all apples are green.

These are all true.